# Regex equals condition except for certain condition

Tags: php, regex

I have written the following Regex in PHP for use within preg_replace().

```
/\b\S*(.com|.net|.us|.biz|.org|.info|.xxx|.mx|.ca|.fr|.in|.cn|.hk|.ng|.pr|.ph|.tv|.ru|.ly|.de|.my|.ir)\S*\b/i
```

This regex removes all URLs from a string pretty effectively this far (though I am sure I can write a better one).  I need to be able to add an exclusion though from a specific domain.  So the pseudo code will look like this:

```
IF string contains: .com or .net or. biz etc... and does not contain: foo.com THEN execute condition.
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: This isn't a URL. You're talking about matching a hostname, and trying to match it against a list of TLDs you have heard of. This is rarely a good idea, since the list of TLDs grows all the time and includes a great many you've missed (although not .xxx which doesn't exist yet).

Comment: if you pop that into the regex.powertoy.org it works pretty well, other TLDs work.  As I said its not the best solution, but it does work for this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<=\s|^)(?!\S*foo\.com)\S*\.(com|net|us|biz|org|info|xxx|mx|ca|fr|in|cn|hk|ng|pr|ph|tv|ru|ly|de|my|ir)\S*\b/im
```

Also, remember that you need to escape the dot - and that you can move it outside the alternation since each of the alternatives starts with a dot.

Comment: I am having problems with the code you posted.  For one on http://regex.powertoy.org/ it still removes a portion of foo.com, it actually removes everything from the point of .com onward including things like /apage.html which would need to be maintained.  Thanks for the step in the right direction though.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I have edited my regex - instead of a simple word boundary (which would often be found within a URL), it's now looking for a space/start of line before the text to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_replace_callback instead.
Let your callback decide whether to replace.

It can give more flexibility if the requirements become too complicated for a simple regex.